# Genexus 17U5 java web, guardar un archivo de texto con información de nombres entre comillas

Tags: java, web, archivo, genexus, texto

Tengo un nombre entre comillas en una variable.
Con el código siguiente, crea el archivo pero al abrirlo observo un nombre con varias comillas.

Ejemplo de código:

```
&path = 'c:\ventas\file.txt'
forma = '"MARIA"'
&w = dfwopen(&path,'','') 
if &w = 0 
    &w = dfwptxt(&forma)
    &w = dfwnext()  
endif   
&w = dfwclose( )
```

El resultado es :  """MARIA"" "
¿Por qué genexus17 genera más comillas de las necesitadas?

Answer (score 0):

Intente probar con `!""`

```
&path = 'c:\Models\file.txt'
&forma = !'"MARIA"'
&w = dfwopen(&path,'','') 
if &w = 0 
    &w = dfwptxt(&forma)
    &w = dfwnext()  
endif   
&w = dfwclose( )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No pude reproducirlo, pero se me ocurre que podrías probar en la línea en la cual asignas el texto con:

```
&forma = CHR(34) + 'MARIA' + CHR(34)
```

en lugar de:

```
&forma = '"MARIA"'
```

Comment: no tampoco funciona con CHR(34) , da el mismo efecto "'""MARIA"""